# Content type header is not setting the other value always application/json

Tags: angular, web-services, symfony

In my application I am using authHttp service to call the get request along with content type header.

```
dowloadReleases(releaseID: number): Observable<any> {
    var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' , 'release-id' : releaseID});
    var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    var endpoint = 'api/releases';
    return this.authHttp.get(endpoint, options).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

The same request was working but after upgrade of angular2 to 4 content type always goes as application/json to the server instead of application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.

Api's are written in symfony (php) framework, form the service side I can able to get the release-id value properly.

Comment: Which exact angular version are you using?

Comment: Are include `Headers & RequestOptions` classes?

Comment: loaded in the service file import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

Comment: angular 4 version

Answer (score 1):

As for Angular 5 and probably beyond, `HttpParams`, `HttpHeaders`, and the likes are *immutable*. From the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) itself, a request can be made this way:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload-file', 
file, {
    headers: headers,
    reportProgress: true
});
```

The above is an example of a POST request with a changed header and listens to the event progress. As you can see, the `set()` method of `HttpHeaders` returns an instance of the class.